# NextJs with PM2 not output logs

Tags: reactjs, express, logging, next.js, pm2

I'm using PM2 to run my NextJs applications in cluster mode, but I only have start-up logs when I check pm2 logs.

```
331|dev-pu | > public-banger@0.0.1 start
331|dev-pu | > next start "--port=3001"
```

version :

pm2 5.2.0

next 13.0.7

And I'm in a nx mono-repo but I think there is no impact.

My command to run an application look like this

`pm2 start npm -i 1 --merge-logs --name dev-public-banger -- start -- --port=3001`

--merge-logs has no impact, I just try few things

and my server.js is this

```js
const rootLogger = require('loglevel');
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const defaultLogger = rootLogger.getLogger('internal');
defaultLogger.setLevel(rootLogger.levels.DEBUG);
const PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT_PUBLIC_BANGER, 10) || 4200;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev, preserveLog: true });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    defaultLogger.log('REQ');
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(PORT, (err) => {
    defaultLogger.log('START');
    if (err) throw err;
    defaultLogger.log(` => Ready on ${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

I need logs from every request and errors to be accessible in pm2 logs, or anything else because today I can't retrieve this logs.

Thank's for the read, if you need more details don't hesitate.